# Pre-sign self-extracting EXE files

Tags: code-signing

I need to generate many self-extracting EXE files, which all differ quite slightly (containing one static EXE file to be run, and a user-provided config file).

I want to avoid having a signing infrastructure on the server that generates these self-extracting EXE files.  Is it possible to sign a container EXE in such a way that I can add the configuration file later?

I tried appending the configuration file to the signed EXE, but that caused the file to appear as unsigned; the signature clearly must be at the end of the file.

Comment: If config is embedded in EXE, there is no way.

Comment: @i486 So, the *only* way this can be achieved is to (1) sign every EXE, or to (2) provide a pre-signed EXE and config file together in another container that doesn't require signing, such as a ZIP?

Comment: Yes. Or put all config files on http/FTP location and download necessary config file at install time / first run.